# addItem not working

Tags: magento-1.9, php

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_css</type>
        <name>css/owl.transitions.css</name>
            <params/>
                <if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]]>   
                </if>
</action>
```

This is my file **page.xml.**

I am using **FireFox browser**. I want add this css.

But I am not able to load the css by this code.

This CSS is locaded under folder **skin/frontend/rwd/supermax/css/**

Please suggest solution to load this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check this link http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/
There are lot of code css broswer condtion for **firefox bcoz of firefox have different versions**  that you need apply `multiple condition` `<action method="addItem">`.

But if you will be `@-moz-document url-prefix() { }` code in `owl.transitions.css` and write all css code at between {} then those css will work for firefox only.

See Details at [Targeting only Firefox with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)